# How do I learn encoding of a text that is encoded at character level?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

Encoded text at character level:

> tvletwgzkrqvuhtwamuluhpkskpmpmiwtvuhamqvmviwlrvikquhtwamuluhqgvipmmvulkriwpmqvtwleuhamqvmviwlrvikquhtwamuluhqgqvqvtwviezlemvxeuhamqvmviwlrvikquhtwamuluhpkskvieniwlrvikquhqvmvuhqgpmpmiwletwulenokuhxepmuhtwiwululentvuhtwamuluhvimvuhsktwlemvezskenuhtwtvuhulqvkrezuhamypmvamdfuhulenamguuhraskvipmyptwqvuhtwamuluhxepmuhvimvenulgzenypuhenuhsatvuhvipmdfuhqgletwsklepmuhulqvlemvxeuhtwamuluhxepmuhtwiwululentvuhenuhqvmvuhpmpmiwletwulenok

Map to one of 10 classes: 0-9.

Comment: As the text is encoded, I cannot apply any of the embeddings (GloVe, Word2Vec) and feed them into RNN or LSTM.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed description of the task you are approaching and the problems you are facing.

Comment: What one might need to solve this is to know how a successfully decoded text would look like. Do you have any samples (would be your training data) or at least the language that the text is in. The latter option would allow you to employ some generic dictionaries to try to find words that are contained in the encoding.

Comment: Assuming the encoding preserves structure, it shouldn't matter. The answer is the same as it would be without: get a bunch of labelled data, pairs of (text, class), train a classifier, then do inference.